# Prove that there is an infinite simple path in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected infinite Graph G.
each vertex in G has a finite rank.

**Prove That :**   Every vertex we choose from G can be a starting vertex for an infinite simple path in G.

Simple Path:  a path that does not contain repeated vertices.

I'm confused on how to start with this kind of "infinite" question ...

what is the suitable approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from a vertex.

If this vertex (and its edges) were removed, there should be at least one of the resulting connected components that is infinite. [*It is not possible to have infinitely many finite connected components because for this the removed vertex would have to have an infinite number of edges.*] So, we choose to move to such infinite component.

After moving there remove the vertex and its edges. You are standing in a graph that have the same properties as the graph you started with.

Induction.

**Advice:** In graph theory many problems can be solved by giving an algorithm that computes what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll take your advice in concern thank you:)